# How to constrain the output of a deep neural network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I would like to preface this by apologizing for the somewhat generalist nature of my question.

I want to fit a DNN classifier that is compiled using a softmax activation with categorical cross-entropy loss to predict the probabilities of 4 classes.

I need to add a constraint on the neural net to take into account one feature value.. for the sake of an example, let's say the 4 classes I want to predict are cat, dog, lion, and ant, and I have a boolean feature "is_pet"  - I want to make sure that the predicted probabilities of lion and ant to be exactly zero ... What is the best way of implementing this constraint? and are there other ways of achieving this by using a different model architecture?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like your network to predict the correct class with the maximum margin (i.e. 100% correct class, 0% the other three classes). You could do this by simply taking the maximum value from the output of the softmax as your predicted class and setting all other predicted probabilities to 0. This operation is discontinuous and will cause issues if you try to back-propagate its gradient through the network, so it is best to do it as the last step.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a mask. You could apply a boolean mask just before the softmax depending on that additional boolean feature that you have.

Depending on the nature of that feature you could have a set of rules that would define this mask, or you could have a network learning how to define such a mask.